# How to set a toast to java.net.UnknownHostException in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In the emulator, I get an error when my internet connection is turned off:

> java.net.UnknownHostException:
>   Unable to resolve host "URL";
>   No address associated with hostname.

But I want to show a Toast instead of revealing my hosting URL upon OnClick of Login Button to prevent any security issues. Please Help :)

```
public class NewLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
  private EditText editTextUsername, editTextPassword;
  private Button buttonLogin;
  private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_login);


    if (SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).isLoggedIn()) {
      finish();
      startActivity(new Intent(this, AdminGMenuActivity.class));
      return;
    }

    editTextUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
    editTextPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    buttonLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");

    buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
  }

  private void userLogin() {
    final String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    progressDialog.show();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(
      Request.Method.POST,
      Constants.URL_LOGIN,
      new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
          progressDialog.dismiss();


          try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
            if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {
              SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                .userLogin(
                  obj.getInt("id"),
                  obj.getString("username"),
                  obj.getString("email")
                );
              startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AdminGMenuActivity.class));
              finish();
            }
            else {
              Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(),
                obj.getString("message"),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
              ).show();
            }
          }

          catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      },
      new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
          progressDialog.dismiss();

          Toast.makeText(
            getApplicationContext(),
            error.getMessage(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
          ).show();
        }
      }
    ) {
      @Override
      protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("username", username);
        params.put("password", password);
        return params;
      }
    };

    RequestHandler.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
  }


  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {

    if (view == buttonLogin) {
      userLogin();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Catch the thrown exception, instead of printing it make it show a `Toast`?

Comment: Thanks for response Sir, Can you please provide me with the code to do that?

Comment: `try { //logging in code } catch (UnknownHostException uhe) { Toast.makeText(this, "Couldn't connect to server!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }`

Comment: Sir, I just did that, but got the following error -

Cannot resolve method 'makeText(anonymous com.android.volley.Response.Listener<java.lang.String>, java.lang.String, int)'

Comment: In your `Toast.makeText()`, instead of `this` write `NewLoginActivity.this`

Comment: Thank You, Sir, it solved that error.
Now am getting another error -

Exception 'java.net.UnknownHostException' is never thrown in the corresponding try block

Answer (score 0):

use try-catch block to catch the exception

```
try {
    //your code for login goes here....
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to connect!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I am now getting this error
Exception 'java.net.UnknownHostException' is never thrown in the corresponding try block

Comment: you can replace it with general exception, so that it'll catch all the eceptions. try {
    //your code for login goes here....
} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to connect!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

Comment: The above error got solved,the app is still showing exception while clicking on the login button.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much, everyone.The error got solved just by commenting out the toast statement inside.

```
             @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    /*Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                           error.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show();*/
                }
```